# React fails on build

Tags: reactjs

Having my app running with "npm start" works well.
When I build it with "npm run build" and point the server to the build-folder, it fails.
The error in console says:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'executeGet' of undefined
```

I have a file common.js that includes some functions. The one that errored is declared this way:

```
const executeGet = async (url, options) => {
    return 'something';
}
module.exports.executeGet = executeGet;
```

Well, it sucks that with npm run it works while when serving the build folder it fails. But what I understand webpack is involved when building and that's maybe there something goes wrong.
I have tried modifying the declaration (but still getting the same error):

```
module.exports.executeGet = async (url) => {
    return 'something';
}
```

Or even this way (but it then says: "Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined")

```
exports.executeGet = async (url) => {
    return 'something';
}
```

My package.json looks like this:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.6",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.5.0",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "react-images-uploader": "^1.2.0-rc1",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.1",
    "react-toastify": "^6.2.0",
    "web-vitals": "^0.2.4"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Looking in chrome dev-tools, under "Sources" I can see that there is this line:

```
e.exports.executeGet = r
```

which is actually undefined. I don't really know what the problem is. Is this about the syntax used to declare exported functions? Which does not relaly work when webpack creates the build?

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using `react-scripts`, you need to export things using the correct ES Modules export/import syntax, not CommonJS `module.exports`:

```
const executeGet = async (url, options) => {
    return 'something';
}
export executeGet;
```

Similarly, if you happen to be using `require()`, you shouldn't; instead use `import`.

Comment: But then I get a lot of errors and cannot be served. Do I need to specify something in common.js maybe?